# Two sequences, one of them bounds difference of the other and converges to $0$. Show that the other sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

That is, let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be sequences such that $b_n \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$ and for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $l \geq k$, 
$$|a_l - a_k| < b_k\text{.}$$
Show that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy.

My guess is that $a_n \to 0$. So, we could try working from the definition of convergence and show that $a_n \to 0$, but it isn't clear to me how to show that $|a_n| < \epsilon$.

**Hints**, not complete solutions, are appreciated.

**Edit**: Could the squeeze theorem potentially be useful here?

Comment: Did you want  $b_k$ on the right?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, thank you.

Comment: No, $a_n$ need not approach $0.$ Consider $a_n = 1$ for all $n.$

Comment: @zhw. Ah, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $N$ such that $b_n <\epsilon$ for $n\ge N.$ What happens if $k,l\ge N?$

Comment: If $k, l \geq N$, then $|x_l - x_k| < b_k < \epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, because the smaller of the indices is $\ge N.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Use the following $|a_{n+m}-a_n|<b_n$ and continue from here. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=0$ then exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have $|b_n|<\varepsilon$. Therefore, $|a_{n+m}-a_n|<|b_n|<\varepsilon$.

Edit: As a response to your answer - the squeeze theorem is useful, and you can use if after this hint I gave you.

Comment: Could the squeeze theorem potentially be useful here?

Comment: Yes it could be useful

Comment: I don't see how this answer is helpful.

Comment: @zhw. Nor do I, to be quite frank.

Comment: Just edited. Hope this helped.